# Interactive transition direction change in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using interactive transitions between tabs in my `UITabBarController`. Everything is smooth except for one thing. For example I have 3 tabs - A, B and C. When I'm on B and user starts panning to the right we need to slide A in and when to the left - we slide C in. What I need to do is when user starts panning to the right - start sliding A in and when user changes his mind and starts panning to the left instead without releasing the finger - I'd like to be able to start sliding C in immediately.
I've tried implementing it in my gesture handler and I can successfully detect when I need to cancel my previously started transition and start another one in the other direction but I always get stuck trying to cancel interaction controller and set `selectedIndex` properly.

For example:

1) I start with selectedIndex == 1;

2) User starts panning to controller A, I create interaction controller and set selectedIndex = 0;

3) User decides to pan to controller C instead, I cancel my interaction transition but selectedIndex is still 0, so basically now I'm jumping from 0 to 2 and my animation controller goes crazy and my screen is messed up - empty.

How do I do it right? Failed to find examples of this kind of transition, even though it happens everywhere in popular apps, say Tinder for example or Snapchat.